# Floating points in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, floating-point

I am using java in intellij idea and while dealing with floating points but compiler isn't returning absolute value if answer is 0.1 then it is returning 0.099998474

There is sample code I am using:

```java
float f1;
f1 = 66.1f % 6f;
System.out.println(f1);
```

Comment: Hint: 66.1f is actually 66.09999847412109375, as that's the closest exactly-representable 32-bit floating point value.

Comment: For accuracy, use `BigDecimal`.